# How do I run another C program within my C program?

Tags: c, linux, command-line, system

(All programs running on Linux and through command line) So I want to be able to run a compiled C program from within my own C program and then be able to read the output of that compiled C program and have my C program provide input for that program. (Also assume I only have the compiled version of the other C program). I am aware of the system() function, but I am not sure if I can use that to read what the compiled Program outputs and then provide my own input.

Comment: `fork` `pipe` `dup` and `exec` are the functions you should be looking into.

Comment: A simple solution is to redirect the output of your called program to a file and process that file in the calling program.

Comment: Note that if you only need to go *one* way, there's `popen`. When you need to go both ways, there is no simple solution - but beware of deadlocks due to large amounts of data on stdin and/or stdout. Also be aware that some programs access the *terminal* rather than stdin/stdout. The `expect` program may be useful for you.

Answer (score -1):

You need to setup an [inter-process communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) mechanism between your two programs. There are several options to implement this:

- Shared memory / shared files
- Message Queues
- Sockets
- Pipes

You did not give a lot of background on your problem, but from your description it sounds that both your processes run in parallel and exchange data more than once. In this case, you will also have to think about synchronization issues.

A helpful introduction can be found [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/inter-process-communication-ipc/).

Comment: It seems OP doesn't have access to the source code of the called program, only the executable. Some of these solutions can't be implemented in this case.

Answer (score -2):

You can use `system()` like this:

```
system("executable arg1 ... > file.txt");
```

`arg1 ...` is the argument list to the executable. `file.txt` is the output of the executable redirected to a file. This system call can be made in a forked process. The parent program can wait on it. Synchronization tools can be used to enable concurrency if needed on the file `file.txt`.

Comment: You missed "have my C program provide input for that program" part.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Isn't it as simple as passing an argument to the executable in the `system()` call?

Comment: I don't know, it is your answer. Not my -1, though.

Comment: This approach is limited to passing an input to the called program and then retrieve its output. However, the question clearly states that the input to the called program must be given _after_ retrieving the output ("and then provide my own input").